# use EFS certificate on multiple computers to encrypt and read files

Tags: windows, windows-10, encryption, disk-encryption, efs

What I want is to create a single EFS cert for use on multiple computers to encrypt/decrypt files.

I have two computers, **PC1** and **PC2**, and when I try to copy **PC1's** encrypted files to **PC2**, these files can't be opened on **PC2**.

I've exported the certificate from **PC1** [**`user1-cert`**], importing it on **PC2**, and I'm now able to open encrypted files from **PC1** on **PC2**, but when I try to encrypt any other file on **PC2**, they are not encrypted with  **`user1-cert`**; instead, Windows is creating a new certificate on **PC2** [**`user2-cert`**].

I've tried deleting **`user2-cert`**, but when I try to encrypt any new file on **PC2**, Windows is creating a new certificate and encrypting the file with it, preventing decryption on **PC1**.

Comment: Have you checked [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/usmt-migrate-efs-files-and-certificates) or google ([this](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/77268-import-encrypting-file-system-certificate-key-windows-10-a.html) result for example)?

Comment: Do you use the same username ob both computers? I remember that the username is embedded into the EFS certificate. Also check this question: https://superuser.com/q/957541/62676

Answer (score 0):

After importing `user1-cert` on `PC2`, verify that it is selected for use in file encryption, as follows:

- Search for "Manage file encryption certificates" and open it
- Click "Next" until prompted to "Select or create a file encryption certificate"
- If imported correctly, the certificate should appear under a radio button labeled "Use this certificate"; verify the button is selected

If the certificate does not appear in this dialog, then verify the steps taken in importing it.